# "Inner" but not "outter"?

Tags: etymology, orthography, doubled-consonants

in -> inner

out -> outer / (outter?)

What is the history or set of rules behind why 'inner' doubles the 'n' but 'outer' doesn't double the 't'?

Comment: If the *n* were not doubled, you would get *iner*, as in *liner*, which would be intelligible; hence, the double *n*.

Comment: @JimiOke, well, ........that's a weak reason with regards to English, where everything is weak.  The first thing I can think of is the word `proper`.  It doesn't sound like `prōper` and isn't (for some reason) spelled `propper`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Many English words have a double consonant when following a [short](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_length#Traditional_long_and_short_vowels_in_English_orthography) vowel. Consider "biter" and "bitter": the double-t signals that the vowel should be the short i vowel. Thus, you write "inner".

For "outer", "out" is already a two-letter vowel, so it doesn't change sound when you add on other letters at the end, hence "outer".